# Running a python script from jenkins - but can't see the python prints in the output of jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins

I am running Python script from Jenkins
but the prints of Python doesn't shows in the jenkins output

Jenkins output example:
"Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Testing Sanity

```
[Testing Sanity] $ cmd.exe /c call C:\windows\TEMP\shiningpanda6085220944592659293.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Testing Sanity>nosetests 
C:\Users\asafb\PycharmProjects\Sanity_HB_RR_from_Saved_Pos\Check_Newly_Created_Cluster_Monitor.py 

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Testing Sanity>exit 0 
Finished: SUCCESS"
```

Answer (score 1):

I set this on **top of the python script** and the output started showing on the Jenkins Console:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -u
```

Comment: I use this :
"#!/usr/bin/env python -u"
But it doesn't work , 
at the moment I worked around it - writing to log file & echo it - that's shows on the jenkins output

Comment: I don't think this is going to work if python is sitting on windows environment.